# Intellij settings set to CNY currency but I want $ instead

Tags: java, settings, currency

I'm using intellij and I'm a beginner.

I've made a mortgageCalculator. Everytime I print, it displays all my numbers in CNY。 I didn't format anything in my code:

'''
 private static MortgageCalculator calculator;

```
public static void printMortgage(int principle, float annualInterest, byte years) {
    calculator = new MortgageCalculator(principle, annualInterest, years);
    double mortgage = calculator.calculateMortgage();
    String mortgageFormatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(mortgage);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("MORTGAGE");
    System.out.println("----------");
    System.out.println("Mortgage: " + mortgageFormatted);
}

public static void printPaymentSchedule(int principle, byte years, float annualInterest) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("payment Schedule:");
    System.out.println("-----------------");
    for (short month = 1; month <= years * Main.Months_In_Year; month++){
        double balance = MortgageCalculator.calculateBalance(month);
        System.out.println(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(balance));
```

'''

Why am I seeing CNY instead of $. Where in settings can I change it back to $. I use a macbook which was bought in HK, I can type in Simplified Chinese and in English. I did download Intellij from a north american location. Do the intellij 'preferences' or something have to do with it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would help to see how you are displaying your values. Posting the calculations of those values is not helpful in the least here (unless you think that the calculations or their results are also wrong).

Comment: I've updated it, forgive me if I've done it the wrong way. Pure beginner here and I will learn the social norm around here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Locale.US` with `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstanc`e like this:

```cs
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
```

You can use `Locale.UK` for pound and `Locale.JAPAN` for Yen.